# How to get knexjs type definitions in migration files?

Tags: javascript, migration, knex.js, type-definition

KnexJS type definitions work fine in all JS files where I import/require it. But in migrations there is no import/require due to no need of knex initializaion. Type definitions help avoiding error in properties and methods. How can I get type definitions in migration files for KnexJS then?

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  // type definitions dont work here
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. AlhamduLILLAH. I found the answer myself.

```js
/** @typedef {import('knex/types').Knex} knex */

/**
 * 
 * @param {knex} knex 
 */
export const up = async knex => {

  // Start here.. types work here!!

}

/**
 * 
 * @param {knex} knex 
 */
export const down = async knex => {

  // Start here.. types work here!!

}
```